# how to let jacoco know sources/classes are outside the module

Tags: maven, jacoco

Module A is a separate module having all the integration tests. Maven-Jacoco-Sonar works fine, if sources and tests are located at one module.

Since module A is a different module altogether, we couldn't be able to generate the jacoco reports easily. Because, jacoco is unable to find the sources within module A to measure the coverage for report. Source files are all residing at different modules. jacoco needs to have the class files and source files available in order to generate a report. We need to link up them to module A accordingly while generating the jacoco report so that, jacoco-it.exec can be easily pulled to Sonar to display the coverage analysis.

Currently in this case,
Classes triggered according to the jacoco agent but no source/class files available

Please help me if anyone has as solution how to achieve the above functionality. It would be so helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following as your main src

```
 def debugTree = [fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter),
                 fileTree(dir: "${project(":your_module_name").projectDir}/build/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)]
 def mainsrc = [fileTree(dir:"${project(":your_module_name").projectDir}/src/main/java"),
                     fileTree(dir:"${project.projectDir}/src/main/java")]
 sourceDirectories = files(mainsrc)
 classDirectories = files(debugTree)
```

This will include your external sub module files to be used while creating the jacoco report.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting sourcesets variable.

```
    jacocoTestReport {
        sourceSets project(':module_name').sourceSets.main
        reports {
            xml.enabled true
//            enable html report for debugging in local env
//            html.enabled true
//            html.destination = file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
        }
    }
```